# Installing aChartEngine for use with ecilpse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, achartengine

I am having trouble understanding how to set up achartengine to incorporate into an existing android project using eclipse.

I have downloaded this file: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0-javadocs.zip&can=2&q=

Could someone please show me how to set this up for use with eclipse?

Comment: you need to add the jar to the projects libs folder have you done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download [this](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0.jar&can=2&q=) (the library, not the docs!)

And copy it to your libs folder

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the delayed answer - we have different fuses, I guess.